# How to properly implement error handling for 500 error in node js

Tags: node.js

I am using Node JS to build a web server.

I don't get at the moment how I can properly catch and throw errors.  I want to see if there's an error happens I want to throw the error to the top...  The app.js is running at local host 3000, but it does not route to index.js so my application does not display anything from the controller.

The standard Express.js error handler code is below, but we're going to start off simpler:

Add the code below to add a Not Found error that runs only if no other endpoint is triggered.

```
// server.js

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if(err.status == 404) {
  //do logging and user-friendly error message display
    res.redirect('/404.html');
  } else if (err.status == 500) {
    res.redirect('/500.html');
  }
});
```

I tried to handle error on my app.js file:

```
//app.js
//**** DEPENDENCIES ****//
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//use the express handlebars
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


// **** CONTROLLERS **** //

const index = require('./controllers/index');


//**** MIDDLEWARE ****//
// static files will live in the public folder
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/', index);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if(err.status == 404) {
    res.status(err.status || 404);
    res.render('error', {err : err.status, message: "Sorry We Can't Help You", stack: err.stack });
  } else if (err.status == 500) {
    console.log(500);
    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {err : err.status});
    // res.redirect('/500.html');
  }
});

// **** CONTROLLERS **** //
// separate the route from the app.js to make it cleaner
require('./controllers/index.js')(app);


// **** Local server Port **** //
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, function(req, res) {
  console.log("Express App listening on port " + PORT + "...");
});
```

Comment: All your routes need to come before your error handling functions. And in those routes, you need to return an error to the next function in line for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but have you tried `app.get('/', index);` instead of `app.use('/', index);`